# How to use a string to search in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a string that needs to be evaluated as code. But how can I achieve this so I can search an array with this string?

The values that are inserted in the function are predefined. So I can only change the function.

```
function setIn(a, b, c)
{
    console.log('Debug session 603 started')
    var x = ""

    b.forEach(function(element, i) {
        x = x + "['" + element + "']"
    });

    console.log(x)
    a[x] = c
    return a
}

setIn(
    {
        "a": "asdf", 
        "b": {
            "b1": "wrong",
            "b2": "asdf"
        }
    },
    ['b', 'b1'],
    "good"
)
```

**Expected:**

```
{ 
    "a": "asdf",
    "b": {
        "b1": "good",
        "b2": "asdf"
    }
}
```

**My current result:**

```
{ 
    "a": "asdf",
    "b": {
        "b1": "wrong",
        "b2": "asdf"
    },
    "['b']['b1']": "good"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
function setIn(a, b, c){
    var x = "a"
    b.forEach(function(element, i) {
        x = x + "['" + element + "']"
    });
    x = x + "= c";
    eval(x)
    return a
}
```

This might not be the most pretty, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually set the new value inside the `forEach` loop when you are accessing the last `key` on the `b` array. Otherwise you can go one level deep inside the object.

```js
function setIn(a, b, c)
{
    console.log('Debug session 603 started');
    var x;

    b.forEach(function(element, i)
    {
        // If we are accessing the last key, assign c to it.
        // Else, access the new key.

        if (i === b.length - 1)
            (x || a)[element] = c;
        else
            x = (x || a)[element];
    });

    return a;
}

let res = setIn(
    {
      "a": "asdf", 
      "b": {"b1": "wrong", "b2": "asdf"}
    },
    ['b', 'b1'],
    "good"
);

console.log(res);
```